# Program like airvideo

Tags: video-streaming

Is there a program like airvideo for ipad, for the PC.
That is, an app that can create a net tunnel and live transcode a video stream server to computer.

Comment: Do you want the live transcode, or do you just want a really nice UI to play any of your movies over the network? PCs don't tend to need the transcode step because they can just decode the original format anyway.

Comment: Sometimes if the file is 1080p and the network has lag it is useful to have Transcoding.